# How to copy files from any location to Resources/Images Folder in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Is it somehow possible to copy the contents of a directory into the AppData directory of a MAUI Windows application at runtime to be able to work with it?

So far I have only managed to load existing images from the Resources/Images folder at compile time. But I need to be able to load new images all the time.

I already tried to load an image with an absolute path, but that doesn't seem to work.

xaml.cs file:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("Y:/Images/");
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "dotnet_bot.svg");
    img.Source = filePath;
}
```

xaml file:

```
<Image x:Name="img"
    SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
    HeightRequest="200"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: We had an extensive discussion about this yesterday.  Why are you asking about this again?  There are restrictions about which folders Windows Storage allows apps to access.

Comment: Because it didn't work.

Comment: Your post doesn't give any indication that you have actually tried anything I suggested, or that you have read the documentation I pointed you to regarding UWP file access permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ImageSource, not image.

And try the method FromFile.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.imagesource.fromfile?view=net-maui-7.0
(I use this for Android/IOS and it works)

Anyway, if you somehow get the file content, you do not have to actually make a file in the AppData.
You can plain and simple use the stream:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.imagesource.fromstream?view=net-maui-7.0